# issues when trying to push a local repo to a github repo

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote

I'm brand new to git and I'm having major issue when trying to push a local repo to github. I set up a remote repo called origin with my github repo SSH address. Then when I try to push I keep getting the following issues:

```
Macintosh:thinkful projects adityagorti6$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:speedrage56/Thinkful-Repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:speedrage56/Thinkful-Repo.git (push)
Macintosh:thinkful projects adityagorti6$ git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your public key that you uploaded to GitHub doesn't work with the private key on your computer. You should follow the [instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) with uploading your public key.

Alternatively, you could use the [HTTP protocol](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support), but it's not as suited to this task.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the guide to setup a new git repository on github?, by that I mean that you have to add your public key on github so you can login later with it, here is a link showing the process:

[Github guide](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

Hope you get it working :)